# fetch a particular value using node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to try to fetch a field value from MongoDB using Node.js. But it shows me `undefined` in my console. My requirement is to print the data in the console or browser from MongoDB using Node.js.

1). This is my node js

```
this.levelChange = function(req, res, next){
    try{
        var query = {'level_num':2};
        QuizLevel.find(query,function(err,data){
            var a = data.min_score;
            console.log(a);
            res.send(a);
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error");
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

2). This is my js-schema

```
{
    _id:{type:String},
    age:{type:Number},
    level_num:{type:String},
    min_score:{type:String},
    max_questions:{type:String}
}
```

3).This is my console output

```
undefined
```

4). This is my JSON data

```
{
  "age":5,
  "level_num":1,
  "min_score":10,
  "max_questions":30
},
{
  "age":5,
  "level_num":2,
  "min_score":12,
  "max_questions":33
}
```

Comment: `console.log(data);` see output in console, is data contains your column or not?

Comment: you are retrieving multiple records is database so you have to use loop get data or you can also use index like data[0].min_score;

Answer (score 2):

Simply use findOne(find return an array of document) with a project field(return only desired fields).

And don't forget to check the err field !

```
try{
    var query = {'level_num':2};
    QuizLevel.findOne(query,{min_score: 1}, function(err,data){
        if(err || !data)
        {
           console.log(err);
           return next(err);
        }
        else
        {
          var a = data.min_score;
          console.log(a);
          res.send(a);
        }
    });
}catch(err){
    console.log("Error");
    return next(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect but it looks like you're trying to access object property while the result is a collection, see:

```
data.min_score // => [{ ... }, { ... }].min_score
```

vs

```
data[0].min_score
```

What you want to achieve is something like:

```
var scores = data.map((function (item) {
  return item.min_score;
});

console.log(scores);
```

You can always check the type of result with `console.log(typeof data)` or simply write `console.log(data)`, sometimes `console.log(Object.keys(data))` come in handy as well for simple debugging not to mention node-inspector.

Comment: i am getting this [ undefined ]